# PHP "Undefined Index" multidimensional array with nested index

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I actually had this code working just fine, but I did some things to make it look a lot more clean and concise by using array keys. You can see how my first go at it is kind of sloppy looking with the keys being `$classes[$i+3]` etc. It works fine, but I wanted to make it more readable and make more sense at a glance.

This is the error message:

> Notice: Undefined index: A in C:\xampp\htdocs\CreateaTranscript.php on line 127
>       ("A" is a key in the "$grade_conversion" array that relates to a decimal value for computing the user's GPA.)

This is the line of code I use to have that actually worked:

```
$grade_points += $grade_conversion[$classes[$i+3]] * $classes[$i+2];
```

This is the line of code causing the error:

```
$grade_points += $grade_conversion[$course[$i]['grade']] * $course[$i]['credit_hours'];
```

I tried enclosing the multi-dimensional array in 's. However, it just creates a different error that prevents the script from running. I know the basic issue is that the compiler sees an array key not enclosed in 's. However, why does it work with the normal array and not the multi-dimensional array?

```
$grade_conversion=array(
    'A' => 4,
    'A-' => 3.7,
    'B+' => 3.3,
    'B' => 3.0,
    'B-' => 2.7,
    'C+' => 2.3,
    'C' => 2.0,
    'C-' => 1.7,
    'D+' => 1.3,
    'D' => 1,
    'D+' => 0.7,
    'F' => 0,
);
```

I was trying to keep this concise. Is it possible to use an index in the manner I declared it? It worked fine before I switched it over to a multi-dimensional array. I'm going to add a sample of the for statement that the line was from:

```
for($i = 0;$i < count($course);$i++){
print "<tr bgcolor = 'F8F8F8'><td>" . $course[$i]['course_id'] . "<td>" . $course[$i]['course_name'] . "</td><td>" . $course[$i]['credit_hours'] . "</td><td>" . $course[$i]['grade'] . "</td></tr>";

//Keep a running count of credit hours for the GPA equation.
//Keep a running total of grade points using the $grade_conversion array
$total_credit_hours += $course[$i]['credit_hours'];
$grade_points += $grade_conversion[$course[$i]['grade']] * $course[$i]['credit_hours'];

}
```

The $course array is create by reading data from a file.

Here is how the $course array is created. The data is pulled from a data file line by line.

```
            $fh=fopen($file, "r");
        $j = 0;
        while (!feof($fh)){
                $course[$j]['course_id'] = fgets($fh);
                $course[$j]['course_name'] = fgets($fh);
                $course[$j]['credit_hours'] = fgets($fh);
                $course[$j]['grade'] = fgets($fh);
                $j++;
        }
        fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Can you share an example of your array structure

Comment: And you're sure it's not `$course[$i]['credit_hours']` causing the issue?

Comment: Can you show examples of `$course`, `$i` and `$grade_conversions` at the point of the error? Best example would be to add `var_dump($course, $i, $grade_conversions)` above line 127

Comment: Could be your `$course` array isn't using contiguous indexes. You can probably simplify that loop with `foreach ($course as $courseItem)`, then use `$courseItem` in place of `$course[$i]`

Comment: Also, going to go out on a limb here and guess that you have some unexpected whitespace in your `$course[$i]['grade']` value. Try `$grade_conversion[trim($course[$i]['grade'])]`

Comment: For whatever reason I've had a terrible time getting for each to work, which I finally think I understand. Also you are right about the white space thing. I just changed the way the files were saved so that I could implement this key index set up as opposed to the difficult to read and understand $course[$i+3] nonsense I was doing before. Thanks Phil!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above, your values will include some whitespace characters thanks to `fgets`. You'll need to `trim()` them when you store them in the the `$course` array or when using them as an index for `$grade_conversions`.

You can also avoid manually specifying array indexes when populating your array, eg

```
while (!feof($fh)){
    $course[] = [
        'course_id' => trim(fgets($fh)),
        'course_name' => trim(fgets($fh)),
        'credit_hours' => trim(fgets($fh)),
        'grade' => trim(fgets($fh))
    ];
}
```

and iterating it

```
foreach ($course as $courseItem) {
    $total_credit_hours += $courseItem['credit_hours'];
    // etc
}
```

And finally, I think just about any structured text format (JSON, XML, CSV) would be better than un-keyed, newline separated values, eg

```
// file.json
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Foo",
    "credit_hours": 2,
    "grade": "A"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Bar",
    "credit_hours": 14,
    "grade": "B"
}]
```

and load it...

```
$courses = json_decode(file_get_contents('file.json'), true);
```

Comment: That's definitely a more efficient way to build the array. Thanks again man. Making my code more concise and readable is precisely what I'm trying to get better at and this is definitely another step in the right direction. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I'm not very experienced with reading/writing to files, which is probably why this was causing me so much difficulty. Hopefully I can learn how to do it in the formats you mentioned in the future.

Comment: @user3479482 I just added a quick JSON example